# JavaScript back button to display previous list

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, jquery-events

I want create a web application that display a list of items. Suppose I have displayed a list view (say listobject1) of 3 items. when clicked on any of them I get new list view (say listobject2) which its value is according to listobject1. When again I click one of them I get another view. Now when I click back button i want to go back to previous list view i.e. when I'm now on listobject2 and again when back button is pressed I want to show listobject1. Can anybody tell me how I can do this in JavaScript?

*Edit*
I'm still study about the stuff but I can't solve this problem yet. In order to clarify my problem now, here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#result").hide();
$("input[name='indexsearch']").live("click", function()  {
    
    $("#result").show();
    $("#result").empty();

    loading_img();
    var $textInput = $("[name='valueLiteral']").val();

    $.getJSON("get_onto", {
        "input" : $textInput
    }, function(json) {
        if(json.length > 0 ) {
            var arrayPredicate = [];
            var arrayObject = [];
            var arraySubject = [];
            $.each(json, function(index, value) {
                arraySubject[index] = value.subject;
                arrayPredicate[index] = value.predicate;
                if(value.objectGeneral != null) {
                    arrayObject[index] = value.objectGeneral;
                } else {
                    arrayObject[index] = value.objectLiteral;
                }
            }

            );
            var stmt = [];
            //concat all related array into string (create triple statement)
            $.each(arrayPredicate, function(k,v){
                stmt[k] = "<span class='subject' id="+arraySubject[k]+">" 
                    + arraySubject[k] + "</span> " + " -> " + v + " : "+ 
                     //change object from text to be button form
                    "<button class = 'searchAgain-button'  name = 'searchMore' \n\
                    value = " + arrayObject[k] + ">" + arrayObject[k] + "</button><br>       <br>";
            });
            stmt = stmt.sort();
            $.each(stmt, function(k,v){
                $("#result").append(v);
            });
        } else {
            var $noresult = "No Result : Please enter a query";
            $("#result").append($noresult);
        }
    });

    
});

$("button").live("click", function() {
    $("#result").show();
    $("#result").empty();

    loading_img();
    var $textInput = $(this).attr("Value");
    //var $textInput = "G53SQM";

    $.getJSON("get_onto", {
        "input" : $textInput
    }, function(json) {
        if(json.length > 0 ) {
            var arrayPredicate = [];
            var arrayObject = [];
            var arraySubject = [];
            $.each(json, function(index, value) {
                arraySubject[index] = value.subject;
                arrayPredicate[index] = value.predicate;
                if(value.objectGeneral != null) {
                    arrayObject[index] = value.objectGeneral;
                } else {
                    arrayObject[index] = value.objectLiteral;
                }
            }

            );
            var stmt = [];
            var searchMore = "searchMore";
            //concat all related array into string (create triple statement)
            $.each(arrayPredicate, function(k,v){
                stmt[k] = "<span class='subject' id="+arraySubject[k]+">" + arraySubject[k] + "</span> " + " -> " + v + " : "+ " <button class = 'searchAgain-button' name = " +searchMore + " value = " + arrayObject[k] + ">" + arrayObject[k] + "</button><br><br>";
        });
            stmt = stmt.sort();
            $.each(stmt, function(k,v){
                $("#result").append(v);
            });
        } else {
            var $noresult = "No Result : Please enter a query";
            $("#result").append($noresult);
        }
    });      
});
```

At first, user only see one button name "valueLiteral". After user  perform 1st search, the result is return in a form of JSON and eventually put in stmt[] to display, which at this state the second button was create as a clickable-result which will automatically take the value of result and do second search if user click the second button.
Now the problem is, I want to add a 3rd HTML button name "back" to make the web display the previous result in stmt[] if user click on the button.

Hope this helps in clarify the problems, I'm still doing a hard work on this stuff since I'm a newbie in JavaScript. Appreciate all helps.

Comment: When you say Back Button do you mean just a html button, or the browser's back button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://html5demos.com/history/) is what you want almost exactly the way you want it.

You'll have to use `history.pushState` to push these fake events into the history.

Alternatively, you can use `location.hash` to store the current object, and update the `hash` every time you display a new list. Then `onhashchange` find the `hash` and display the appropriate list.

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/cFwME/

```
var history=[new Array(),new Array()];
history[0].id="#back";
history[1].id="#next";
Array.prototype.last=function(){
    return this[this.length-1];
}
$('#list>li:not(:first)').click(function(){
    if(!history[0].length || history[0].last().html()!=$('#list').html()){
        history[0].push($('#list').clone(true,true));
        $(history[0].id).prop('disabled',false);
        history[1].length=0;
        $(history[1].id).prop('disabled',true);
    }
    $('#list>li:first').html('This is List '+$(this).index());
});
$('#back').click(getHistory(0));
$('#next').click(getHistory(1));

function getHistory(n){
    return function(){
        if(!history[n].length){return false;}
        history[(n+1)%2].push($('#list').replaceWith(history[n].last()));
        history[n].pop();
        $(history[(n+1)%2].id).prop('disabled',false);
        if(!history[n].length){$(history[n].id).prop('disabled',true);}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery BBQ - http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/